# Passing proper JSON objects to Ember.js from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I'm using ember-rails (0.13.0), ember-data-source (0.13), and ember-source (1.0.0.rc6.2).

In my Rails controller, I have:

```
respond_to :json, :html

def index
  @organizations = Organization.approved.limit(25)
  respond_with @organizations
end
```

On the client-side, I've got this model:

```
Whistlr.Organization = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
```

And this `organizations` template:

```
ul
  each organization in model
    li = organization
```

This renders a list of:

```
<Whistlr.Organization:ember335:null>
```

It looks like the organizations are not being properly set by the model. I'm not sure what could be causing this, but my best guess is that the JSON is improperly structured:

```
{"organizations":[{"organizations":{"name":"West-Nikolaus","id":null,"image":{"url":null}}},{"organizations":{"name":"Ward LLC","id":null,"image":{"url":null}}}, . . . ]}
```

Note that each organization is nested with an "organizations" hash which is in turn nested inside another "organizations" hash. I'm assuming the double nesting isn't suppose to happen. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), by default Rails doesn't render the exact format that Ember-Data wants, however AMS has been designed from scratch to work out of the box with ember.

Comment: JSON is coming through properly now. Thanks a lot!